# Placing roof tiles using mathematics

Tags: geometry

I'm no mathematician, but I have this very specific problem with regards to placing objects in a 3D programme. You can imagine this object as an L-shape in 2D space, let's call it $L$, where the horizontal side $a$ is length $0.25$ and the vertical side $b$ is length $1.5$. The angle between $a$ and $b$ is $90°$. The vertex at the top of $b$ is $P$, and the right vertex of $a$ is $Q$. $b$ must intersect $(0,0)$, and $Q$ is locked to the Y axis. As $Q$ moves along the Y axis $P$ draws a curve, let's call that $N$. There is a straight line $M$, which could be anywhere and at any angle. I need a way to determine at which coordinates $N$ intersects $M$, if any, where the coordinates of $N$ are both greater than $0$. Apologies for any poor choices of the notation.

[image: Crude diagram]

Edit 1:

So I think I know how to calculate the coordinates of $P$ given a certain value for $Q$, just a bit of trigonometry. The problem is that I don't know how to intersect $N$ and $M$, because the input to the function that creates $N$ is $Q$, and $N$ outputs both $x$ and $y$ coordinates, whereas the function to create $M$ has the $x$ coordinate known to begin with and only the $y$ as the output, so it doesn't seem like quadratics applies here?

Here is how I calculated $P$:

[image: Crude diagram]

- Take an L-shape $L$, where the horizontal line $b = \overleftrightarrow{RQ} = 0.25$, and the vertical line $a = \overleftrightarrow{PR} = 1.5$. Same as above but I changed the notation to make it easier to understand.
- $\angle PRQ = 90°$.
- $\overleftrightarrow{PR}$ must intersect $(0,0)$.
- $S$ is at the origin.
- $Q$ must be locked to the y-axis. The distance $Q$ is along the Y-axis is $SQ$, and is the input to the function that creates the curve $N$.
- $T$ is directly below $P$ and on the X-axis.

$$\angle RSQ = \angle SPT = \arcsin(\overleftrightarrow{SQ} / \sin(90°) \cdot 0.25)$$
$$\angle SQR = \angle PST = 180 - 90° - \angle RSQ$$
$$\overleftrightarrow{RS} = \overleftrightarrow{SQ} / \sin(90°) \cdot \sin(\angle SQR)$$
$$\overleftrightarrow{SP} = 1.5 - \overleftrightarrow{RS}$$
$$xP = \overleftrightarrow{SP} / \sin(90°) \cdot \sin(\angle RSQ)$$
$$yP = \overleftrightarrow{SP} / \sin(90°) \cdot \sin(\angle SQR)$$

Comment: $P$ is a point, $M$ is a line. What do you mean by "$P$ intersects $M$"?

Comment: You want to know where an arbitrary line intersects a specific point? Well, IF the line 'intersects' the point P, then P will be the point of intersection. Otherwise, there is no answer. Are you sure that M is arbitrary and that you've described the problem accurately?

Comment: This is what I meant by my bad notation, sorry. As 'Q' moves along the Y axis 'P' draws a curve, let's call it 'N'. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I think we need a picture. (At least I do.)

Comment: Made a crude image.

Comment: Made a big edit to the question, see edit 1. I think that is how to calculate $P$, but still not sure how to determine the point of intersection between $N$ and $M$.

Comment: As $Q$ moves down it pulls $P$ along with it, so that at the end $P$ must be at the origin, and the $y$ axis is the hypotenuse of the triangle. So your picture of the curve $N$ isn't quite right. I may have a chance tomorrow to think about the equation for the curve $N$.

Comment: Updated the top image so the rough prediction of $N$ is more accurate. I'm starting to think that there is an obvious quadratic formula for $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $|PC|=b=1.5$, $|QC|=a=0.25$,
and a general equation for the line

\begin{align} 
M:&\quad ux+vy+w=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

The curve $N$ (the locus of points $P$)
can be parameterized with parameter $t\in[0,b]$:
$t=|OP|$.

The coordinates of the point $P$ in terms of $t$ are: 
\begin{align} 
P_x&=t\cos\phi
,\quad
P_y=t\sin\phi
,\quad
\phi=\angle CQO
.
\end{align}

Excluding $\phi$ with
\begin{align} 
\tan\phi&=\frac{b-t}a
,\\
\cos\phi&=
\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\tan^2\phi}}
=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
,\\
\sin\phi&=\tan\phi\cos\phi
=\frac{b-t}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
,
\end{align}

we get $N=N(t).\ t\in[0.b]$ as

\begin{align} 
N(t)&=\left(
\frac{at}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
,
\frac{(b-t)t}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
\right)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

substitution of \eqref{2} into \eqref{1} gives
the equation in terms of $t$:

\begin{align}
u\cdot
\frac{at}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
+
v\cdot
\frac{(b-t)t}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+t^2-2tb}}
+w&=0
\\
\text{or }\quad
v^2 t^4-2 (a u+b v)v t^3
+((a u+b v)^2-w^2) t^2+2b w^2 t
-w^2\,(a^2+b^2)
&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

If there is some $t$ as a solution of \eqref{3}
which fits in the interval $[0,b]$,
there is 
a corresponding intersection $M\cap N=P=N(t)=M(t)$.

For example, let
\begin{align}
u&=5,\quad v=7,\quad w=-8
,\\
M:&\quad 5x+7y-8=0
.
\end{align}
\eqref{3} becomes
\begin{align}
49t^4-\tfrac{329}2\,t^3
+\tfrac{1185}{16}\,t^2
+192t-148 
&= 0
\end{align}

with four real roots,
\begin{align}
t_1&\approx -1.073737808
,\\
t_2&\approx 0.9479508787
,\\
t_3&\approx 1.485999356
,\\
t_4&\approx 1.996930431
.
\end{align}

The two solutions, 
$t_2$ and $t_3$ are in the range $[0,1.5]$,
and corresponding points of intersections 
are $N(t_2)\approx (0.391057,0.86353)$
and $N(t_3)\approx (1.48367,0.083)$.

[image]

Comment: Whoa. That's an order of magnitude more complicated than what I thought it was going to be. I'm so impressed. It's laid out so professionally. I'm in awe of how you might have done it. I'll have to put it into a script, there's no way I'm using a calculator for this.

Comment: @KalciferKandari:
Thanks. You can
check out
[Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/),
this tool has everything to solve/simulate
the questions of this kind.